# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'keys' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, sorting

I have these data in my console.

[image]

```
var uniqVisitorDeviceType = visitorDeviceType.reduce((acc, val) => {
  acc[val] = acc[val] === undefined ? 1 : acc[val] += 1;
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(uniqVisitorDeviceType)
```

I'm trying to access the array keys only.

I've tried

```
console.log(uniqVisitorDeviceType.prototype​.keys())
```

I got

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'keys' of undefined

How would one go about and debug this further?

Comment: Did you mean [`Object.keys(uniqVisitorDeviceType)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)?

Comment: That's an object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an `Object`, not an `array`. Use [`Object.keys(uniqVisitorDeviceType)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) instead.

Comment: yep, that's working. I got an object and array mixed up. sorry and thanks ‍♂️