# Plotly Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of undefined at HTMLCanvasElement

Tags: python, html, plotly

I have generated a scatter matrix using px.scatter_matrix()

```py
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter_matrix(df,
    dimensions=["sepal_width", "sepal_length", "petal_width", "petal_length"],
    color="species")
fig.show()

fig.write_html("/.../scattermatrix.html",
include_plotlyjs="cdn")
```

I then:

1. Open the file scattermatrix.html with Chrome
2. Save the file to create scattermatrixV2.html
3. Open the new saved scattermatrixV2.html

The new saved flashes into view and hten dissapers:
[image: V1 vs V2 Plot now working]

I can see the following error:
[image: ERROR OF scattermatrixV2.html]

```
VM5129 plotly-latest.min.js.download:61 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of undefined
    at HTMLCanvasElement.<anonymous> (VM6 plotly-latest.min.js.download:61)
    at o (VM6 plotly-latest.min.js.download:20)
    at Array.Y.data (VM6 plotly-latest.min.js.download:20)
    at e (VM6 plotly-latest.min.js.download:61)
    at Object.c.syncOrAsync (VM6 plotly-latest.min.js.download:61)
    at Object.r.plot (VM6 plotly-latest.min.js.download:61)
    at Object.r.newPlot (VM6 plotly-latest.min.js.download:61)
    at characterization.php.html:785
(anonymous) @ VM5129 plotly-latest.min.js.download:61
o @ VM5129 plotly-latest.min.js.download:20
Y.data @ VM5129 plotly-latest.min.js.download:20
e @ VM5129 plotly-latest.min.js.download:61
c.syncOrAsync @ VM5…
```

I only have this issue with Plotly plots: scatter matrix and go.Figure(data=      go.Parcoords.., while with the other plots i generate (px.parallel_categories, go.Figure() & fig.add_trace(go.Scatter... ) it works fine.

It seems to be simlar to [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'keys' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55697075/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-keys-of-undefined) however i am not sure where to apply: "Use Object.keys(uniqVisitorDeviceType) instead."

Here is the scatter matrix V1 original  file:

```html
<html>
<head><meta charset="utf-8" /></head>
<body>
    <div>
        
                <script type="text/javascript">window.PlotlyConfig = {MathJaxConfig: 'local'};</script>
        <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>    
            <div id="4cadf67b-95de-4ee0-824e-ab5b83efea70" class="plotly-graph-div" style="height:100%; width:100%;"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                
                    window.PLOTLYENV=window.PLOTLYENV || {};
                    
                if (document.getElementById("4cadf67b-95de-4ee0-824e-ab5b83efea70")) {
                    Plotly.newPlot(
                        '4cadf67b-95de-4ee0-824e-ab5b83efea70',
                        [{"diagonal": {"visible": false}, "dimensions": [{"axis": {"matches": true}, "label": "sepal width", "values": [3.5, 3.0, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4, 3.4, 2.9, 3.1, 3.7, 3.4, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.4, 3.9, 3.5, 3.8, 3.8, 3.4, 3.7, 3.6, 3.3, 3.4, 3.0, 3.4, 3.5, 3.4, 3.2, 3.1, 3.4, 4.1, 4.2, 3.1, 3.2, 3.5, 3.1, 3.0, 3.4, 3.5, 2.3, 3.2, 3.5, 3.8, 3.0, 3.8, 3.2, 3.7, 3.3]}, {"axis": {"matches": true}, "label": "sepal length", "values": [5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5.0, 5.4, 4.6, 5.0, 4.4, 4.9, 5.4, 4.8, 4.8, 4.3, 5.8, 5.7, 5.4, 5.1, 5.7, 5.1, 5.4, 5.1, 4.6, 5.1, 4.8, 5.0, 5.0, 5.2, 5.2, 4.7, 4.8, 5.4, 5.2, 5.5, 4.9, 5.0, 5.5, 4.9, 4.4, 5.1, 5.0, 4.5, 4.4, 5.0, 5.1, 4.8, 5.1, 4.6, 5.3, 5.0]}, {"axis": {"matches": true}, "label": "petal width", "values": [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.6, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]}, {"axis": {"matches": true}, "label": "petal length", "values": [1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7, 1.4, 1.5, 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.6, 1.4, 1.1, 1.2, 1.5, 1.3, 1.4, 1.7, 1.5, 1.7, 1.5, 1.0, 1.7, 1.9, 1.6, 1.6, 1.5, 1.4, 1.6, 1.6, 1.5, 1.5, 1.4, 1.5, 1.2, 1.3, 1.5, 1.3, 1.5, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.6, 1.9, 1.4, 1.6, 1.4, 1.5, 1.4]}], "hoverlabel": {"namelength": 0}, "hovertemplate": "species=setosa<br>%{xaxis.title.text}=%{x}<br>%{yaxis.title.text}=%{y}", "legendgroup": "species=setosa", "marker": {"color": "#636efa", "symbol": "circle"}, "name": "species=setosa", "showlegend": true, "type": "splom"}, {"diagonal": {"visible": false}, "dimensions": [{"axis": {"matches": true}, "label": "sepal width", "values": [3.2, 3.2, 3.1, 2.3, 2.8, 2.8, 3.3, 2.4, 2.9, 2.7, 2.0, 3.0, 2.2, 2.9, 2.9, 3.1, 3.0, 2.7, 2.2, 2.5, 3.2, 2.8, 2.5, 2.8, 2.9, 3.0, 2.8, 3.0, 2.9, 2.6, 2.4, 2.4, 2.7, 2.7, 3.0, 3.4, 3.1, 2.3, 3.0, 2.5, 2.6, 3.0, 2.6, 2.3, 2.7, 3.0, 2.9, 2.9, 2.5, 2.8]}, {"axis": {"matches": true}, "label": "sepal length", "values": [7.0, 6.4, 6.9, 5.5, 6.5, 5.7, 6.3, 4.9, 6.6, 5.2, 5.0, 5.9, 6.0, 6.1, 5.6, 6.7, 5.6, 5.8, 6.2, 5.6, 5.9, 6.1, 6.3, 6.1, 6.4, 6.6, 6.8, 6.7, 6.0, 5.7, 5.5, 5.5, 5.8, 6.0, 5.4, 6.0, 6.7, 6.3, 5.6, 5.5, 5.5, 6.1, 5.8, 5.0, 5.6, 5.7, 5.7, 6.2, 5.1, 5.7]}, {"axis": {"matches": true}, "label": "petal width", "values": [1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.3, 1.5, 1.3, 1.6, 1.0, 1.3, 1.4, 1.0, 1.5, 1.0, 1.4, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.0, 1.5, 1.1, 1.8, 1.3, 1.5, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.4, 1.7, 1.5, 1.0, 1.1, 1.0, 1.2, 1.6, 1.5, 1.6, 1.5, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.2, 1.4, 1.2, 1.0, 1.3, 1.2, 1.3, 1.3, 1.1, 1.3]}, {"axis": {"matches": true}, "label": "petal length", "values": [4.7, 4.5, 4.9, 4.0, 4.6, 4.5, 4.7, 3.3, 4.6, 3.9, 3.5, 4.2, 4.0, 4.7, 3.6, 4.4, 4.5, 4.1, 4.5, 3.9, 4.8, 4.0, 4.9, 4.7, 4.3, 4.4, 4.8, 5.0, 4.5, 3.5, 3.8, 3.7, 3.9, 5.1, 4.5, 4.5, 4.7, 4.4, 4.1, 4.0, 4.4, 4.6, 4.0, 3.3, 4.2, 4.2, 4.2, 4.3, 3.0, 4.1]}], "hoverlabel": {"namelength": 0}, "hovertemplate": "species=versicolor<br>%{xaxis.title.text}=%{x}<br>%{yaxis.title.text}=%{y}", "legendgroup": "species=versicolor", "marker": {"color": "#EF553B", "symbol": "diamond"}, "name": "species=versicolor", "showlegend": true, "type": "splom"}, {"diagonal": {"visible": false}, "dimensions": [{"axis": {"matches": true}, "label": "sepal width", "values": [3.3, 2.7, 3.0, 2.9, 3.0, 3.0, 2.5, 2.9, 2.5, 3.6, 3.2, 2.7, 3.0, 2.5, 2.8, 3.2, 3.0, 3.8, 2.6, 2.2, 3.2, 2.8, 2.8, 2.7, 3.3, 3.2, 2.8, 3.0, 2.8, 3.0, 2.8, 3.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.6, 3.0, 3.4, 3.1, 3.0, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 2.7, 3.2, 3.3, 3.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.4, 3.0]}, {"axis": {"matches": true}, "label": "sepal length", "values": [6.3, 5.8, 7.1, 6.3, 6.5, 7.6, 4.9, 7.3, 6.7, 7.2, 6.5, 6.4, 6.8, 5.7, 5.8, 6.4, 6.5, 7.7, 7.7, 6.0, 6.9, 5.6, 7.7, 6.3, 6.7, 7.2, 6.2, 6.1, 6.4, 7.2, 7.4, 7.9, 6.4, 6.3, 6.1, 7.7, 6.3, 6.4, 6.0, 6.9, 6.7, 6.9, 5.8, 6.8, 6.7, 6.7, 6.3, 6.5, 6.2, 5.9]}, {"axis": {"matches": true}, "label": "petal width", "values": [2.5, 1.9, 2.1, 1.8, 2.2, 2.1, 1.7, 1.8, 1.8, 2.5, 2.0, 1.9, 2.1, 2.0, 2.4, 2.3, 1.8, 2.2, 2.3, 1.5, 2.3, 2.0, 2.0, 1.8, 2.1, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 2.1, 1.6, 1.9, 2.0, 2.2, 1.5, 1.4, 2.3, 2.4, 1.8, 1.8, 2.1, 2.4, 2.3, 1.9, 2.3, 2.5, 2.3, 1.9, 2.0, 2.3, 1.8]}, {"axis": {"matches": true}, "label": "petal length", "values": [6.0, 5.1, 5.9, 5.6, 5.8, 6.6, 4.5, 6.3, 5.8, 6.1, 5.1, 5.3, 5.5, 5.0, 5.1, 5.3, 5.5, 6.7, 6.9, 5.0, 5.7, 4.9, 6.7, 4.9, 5.7, 6.0, 4.8, 4.9, 5.6, 5.8, 6.1, 6.4, 5.6, 5.1, 5.6, 6.1, 5.6, 5.5, 4.8, 5.4, 5.6, 5.1, 5.1, 5.9, 5.7, 5.2, 5.0, 5.2, 5.4, 5.1]}], "hoverlabel": {"namelength": 0}, "hovertemplate": "species=virginica<br>%{xaxis.title.text}=%{x}<br>%{yaxis.title.text}=%{y}", "legendgroup": "species=virginica", "marker": {"color": "#00cc96", "symbol": "circle"}, "name": "species=virginica", "showlegend": true, "type": "splom"}],
                        {"dragmode": "select", "legend": {"tracegroupgap": 0}, "template": {"data": {"bar": [{"error_x": {"color": "#2a3f5f"}, "error_y": {"color": "#2a3f5f"}, "marker": {"line": {"color": "#E5ECF6", "width": 0.5}}, "type": "bar"}], "barpolar": [{"marker": {"line": {"color": "#E5ECF6", "width": 0.5}}, "type": "barpolar"}], "carpet": [{"aaxis": {"endlinecolor": "#2a3f5f", "gridcolor": "white", "linecolor": "white", "minorgridcolor": "white", "startlinecolor": "#2a3f5f"}, "baxis": {"endlinecolor": "#2a3f5f", "gridcolor": "white", "linecolor": "white", "minorgridcolor": "white", "startlinecolor": "#2a3f5f"}, "type": "carpet"}], "choropleth": [{"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}, "type": "choropleth"}], "contour": [{"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}, "colorscale": [[0.0, "#0d0887"], [0.1111111111111111, "#46039f"], [0.2222222222222222, "#7201a8"], [0.3333333333333333, "#9c179e"], [0.4444444444444444, "#bd3786"], [0.5555555555555556, "#d8576b"], [0.6666666666666666, "#ed7953"], [0.7777777777777778, "#fb9f3a"], [0.8888888888888888, "#fdca26"], [1.0, "#f0f921"]], "type": "contour"}], "contourcarpet": [{"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}, "type": "contourcarpet"}], "heatmap": [{"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}, "colorscale": [[0.0, "#0d0887"], [0.1111111111111111, "#46039f"], [0.2222222222222222, "#7201a8"], [0.3333333333333333, "#9c179e"], [0.4444444444444444, "#bd3786"], [0.5555555555555556, "#d8576b"], [0.6666666666666666, "#ed7953"], [0.7777777777777778, "#fb9f3a"], [0.8888888888888888, "#fdca26"], [1.0, "#f0f921"]], "type": "heatmap"}], "heatmapgl": [{"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}, "colorscale": [[0.0, "#0d0887"], [0.1111111111111111, "#46039f"], [0.2222222222222222, "#7201a8"], [0.3333333333333333, "#9c179e"], [0.4444444444444444, "#bd3786"], [0.5555555555555556, "#d8576b"], [0.6666666666666666, "#ed7953"], [0.7777777777777778, "#fb9f3a"], [0.8888888888888888, "#fdca26"], [1.0, "#f0f921"]], "type": "heatmapgl"}], "histogram": [{"marker": {"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}}, "type": "histogram"}], "histogram2d": [{"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}, "colorscale": [[0.0, "#0d0887"], [0.1111111111111111, "#46039f"], [0.2222222222222222, "#7201a8"], [0.3333333333333333, "#9c179e"], [0.4444444444444444, "#bd3786"], [0.5555555555555556, "#d8576b"], [0.6666666666666666, "#ed7953"], [0.7777777777777778, "#fb9f3a"], [0.8888888888888888, "#fdca26"], [1.0, "#f0f921"]], "type": "histogram2d"}], "histogram2dcontour": [{"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}, "colorscale": [[0.0, "#0d0887"], [0.1111111111111111, "#46039f"], [0.2222222222222222, "#7201a8"], [0.3333333333333333, "#9c179e"], [0.4444444444444444, "#bd3786"], [0.5555555555555556, "#d8576b"], [0.6666666666666666, "#ed7953"], [0.7777777777777778, "#fb9f3a"], [0.8888888888888888, "#fdca26"], [1.0, "#f0f921"]], "type": "histogram2dcontour"}], "mesh3d": [{"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}, "type": "mesh3d"}], "parcoords": [{"line": {"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}}, "type": "parcoords"}], "pie": [{"automargin": true, "type": "pie"}], "scatter": [{"marker": {"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}}, "type": "scatter"}], "scatter3d": [{"line": {"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}}, "marker": {"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}}, "type": "scatter3d"}], "scattercarpet": [{"marker": {"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}}, "type": "scattercarpet"}], "scattergeo": [{"marker": {"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}}, "type": "scattergeo"}], "scattergl": [{"marker": {"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}}, "type": "scattergl"}], "scattermapbox": [{"marker": {"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}}, "type": "scattermapbox"}], "scatterpolar": [{"marker": {"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}}, "type": "scatterpolar"}], "scatterpolargl": [{"marker": {"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}}, "type": "scatterpolargl"}], "scatterternary": [{"marker": {"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}}, "type": "scatterternary"}], "surface": [{"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}, "colorscale": [[0.0, "#0d0887"], [0.1111111111111111, "#46039f"], [0.2222222222222222, "#7201a8"], [0.3333333333333333, "#9c179e"], [0.4444444444444444, "#bd3786"], [0.5555555555555556, "#d8576b"], [0.6666666666666666, "#ed7953"], [0.7777777777777778, "#fb9f3a"], [0.8888888888888888, "#fdca26"], [1.0, "#f0f921"]], "type": "surface"}], "table": [{"cells": {"fill": {"color": "#EBF0F8"}, "line": {"color": "white"}}, "header": {"fill": {"color": "#C8D4E3"}, "line": {"color": "white"}}, "type": "table"}]}, "layout": {"annotationdefaults": {"arrowcolor": "#2a3f5f", "arrowhead": 0, "arrowwidth": 1}, "coloraxis": {"colorbar": {"outlinewidth": 0, "ticks": ""}}, "colorscale": {"diverging": [[0, "#8e0152"], [0.1, "#c51b7d"], [0.2, "#de77ae"], [0.3, "#f1b6da"], [0.4, "#fde0ef"], [0.5, "#f7f7f7"], [0.6, "#e6f5d0"], [0.7, "#b8e186"], [0.8, "#7fbc41"], [0.9, "#4d9221"], [1, "#276419"]], "sequential": [[0.0, "#0d0887"], [0.1111111111111111, "#46039f"], [0.2222222222222222, "#7201a8"], [0.3333333333333333, "#9c179e"], [0.4444444444444444, "#bd3786"], [0.5555555555555556, "#d8576b"], [0.6666666666666666, "#ed7953"], [0.7777777777777778, "#fb9f3a"], [0.8888888888888888, "#fdca26"], [1.0, "#f0f921"]], "sequentialminus": [[0.0, "#0d0887"], [0.1111111111111111, "#46039f"], [0.2222222222222222, "#7201a8"], [0.3333333333333333, "#9c179e"], [0.4444444444444444, "#bd3786"], [0.5555555555555556, "#d8576b"], [0.6666666666666666, "#ed7953"], [0.7777777777777778, "#fb9f3a"], [0.8888888888888888, "#fdca26"], [1.0, "#f0f921"]]}, "colorway": ["#636efa", "#EF553B", "#00cc96", "#ab63fa", "#FFA15A", "#19d3f3", "#FF6692", "#B6E880", "#FF97FF", "#FECB52"], "font": {"color": "#2a3f5f"}, "geo": {"bgcolor": "white", "lakecolor": "white", "landcolor": "#E5ECF6", "showlakes": true, "showland": true, "subunitcolor": "white"}, "hoverlabel": {"align": "left"}, "hovermode": "closest", "mapbox": {"style": "light"}, "paper_bgcolor": "white", "plot_bgcolor": "#E5ECF6", "polar": {"angularaxis": {"gridcolor": "white", "linecolor": "white", "ticks": ""}, "bgcolor": "#E5ECF6", "radialaxis": {"gridcolor": "white", "linecolor": "white", "ticks": ""}}, "scene": {"xaxis": {"backgroundcolor": "#E5ECF6", "gridcolor": "white", "gridwidth": 2, "linecolor": "white", "showbackground": true, "ticks": "", "zerolinecolor": "white"}, "yaxis": {"backgroundcolor": "#E5ECF6", "gridcolor": "white", "gridwidth": 2, "linecolor": "white", "showbackground": true, "ticks": "", "zerolinecolor": "white"}, "zaxis": {"backgroundcolor": "#E5ECF6", "gridcolor": "white", "gridwidth": 2, "linecolor": "white", "showbackground": true, "ticks": "", "zerolinecolor": "white"}}, "shapedefaults": {"line": {"color": "#2a3f5f"}}, "ternary": {"aaxis": {"gridcolor": "white", "linecolor": "white", "ticks": ""}, "baxis": {"gridcolor": "white", "linecolor": "white", "ticks": ""}, "bgcolor": "#E5ECF6", "caxis": {"gridcolor": "white", "linecolor": "white", "ticks": ""}}, "title": {"x": 0.05}, "xaxis": {"automargin": true, "gridcolor": "white", "linecolor": "white", "ticks": "", "title": {"standoff": 15}, "zerolinecolor": "white", "zerolinewidth": 2}, "yaxis": {"automargin": true, "gridcolor": "white", "linecolor": "white", "ticks": "", "title": {"standoff": 15}, "zerolinecolor": "white", "zerolinewidth": 2}}}, "title": {"text": "Scatter matrix of iris data set"}},
                        {"responsive": true}
                    )
                };
                
            </script>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

### EDIT AFTER TRYING @Mark H solution.

The solution proposed works. We have also found the issue:

When saving the plot opened with Chrome, Chrome changes the content in line 8 (you see that the _saved version is much longer and with many added attributes), so breaking the Plotly graph:
Original line 8:

```html
       <div id="4cadf67b-95de-4ee0-824e-ab5b83efea70" class="**plotly-graph-div**" style="height:100%; width:100%;"></div>
```

After saving from Chrome it chanes the class:
**Notice how the class changes, I believe it is this**

```html
<div id="4cadf67b-95de-4ee0-824e-ab5b83efea70" class="**plotly-graph-div js-plotly-plot**" style="height:100%; width:100%;">...
```

Changing The div above to the one below fixes the issue:

```html
 <div id="4cadf67b-95de-4ee0-824e-ab5b83efea70" class="**plotly-graph-div**" style="height:100%; width:100%;"></div>
```

By only restoring that line to the original version the plot regularly works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say skip the Chrome step and output it with plotly.

```
fig.write_html("/.../scattermatrixV2.html",include_plotlyjs=True)
```

***However***, this will embed the plotly javascript in the HTML, which will make it ***over 3.3 MB***.

If you're going to be exporting a lot to the same folder, you can lower your disk usage significantly by just saving the html like you've been doing, and then changing

```
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="plotly-latest.min.js"></script>`
```

Where `plotly-latest.min.js` is your local copy of the plotly javascript, which you can get with a curl command:

```
curl get https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js > plotly-latest.min.js
```

To substitute the script lines, you can tack this on to your script like so:

```
with open('scattermatrix.html','rt') as f:
  contents = f.read()

contents = contents.replace("https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js","plotly-latest.min.js",1)

with open('scattermatrixV2.html','wt') as f:
  f.write(contents)
```

Comment: Thanks! this solution works. I believe that the issue is related to how Chrome changes the class, thus even by saving with chrome and then changing that line it works.